# A smooth map which has full rank at a point is locally a submersion/immersion.

Tags: differential-geometry, continuity

Let $F:M\rightarrow N$
  be a smooth map between manifolds and let $p\in M$
 .

1. If $dF_{p}$
   is surjective, then there exists a neighbourhood $U$
   of p
   such that $F|_{U}$
   is a submersion.
2. If $dF_{p}$
   is injective, then there exists a neighbourhood $U$
   of $p$
   such that $F|_{U}$
   is an immersion.

I saw this theorem in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. This is his proof:

[image]

What I don't understand is the part where says "by continuity". Is he talking about a function that is continuous? If so, what function is it?

Comment: The function he refers could be the determinant of a minor of the matrix.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2299042/matrices-of-full-rank-is-a-smooth-manifold-proof-clarification for the same question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In coordinates, $\Bbb d F$ is represented by a matrix. Since $\Bbb d F _p$ has full rank, there exists a minor in it of maximal dimension that is non-zero at $p$. The determinant of this minor is a continuous (in fact polynomial, being a sum of products of entries in the matrix) function of the coordinates, so if it's non-zero at $p$, *by continuity* it will be non-zero on some small neighbourhood of $p$, so the rank will be maximal on this neighbourhood.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $U$ is a coordinate neighbourhood of $p$ in $M$, contained in the preimage under $F$ of a coordinate neighbourhood of $F(p)$ in $N$. We have a continuous map
$$ x \in U \subset \mathbb R^n \mapsto (dF)_x \in {\rm M}(n \times m , \mathbb R).$$
(Of course, I used the coordinate charts to identify $U$ with $\mathbb R^n$ and to identify the respective tangent spaces with $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$.)

Since $F$ is a submersion at $x = p$, we know that the $n \times m$ matrix $(dF)_x$ is of maximal rank at $x = p$. *Said another way, at least one of the $m \times m$ submatrices of $(dF)_p$ has non-vanishing determinant.*

This suggests that we should consider the map $g : U  \to \mathbb R^{\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}}$
that sends each point $x \in U$ to an $\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$-component vector containing the determinants of all $m \times m$ submatrices of $(dF)_x$. Clearly $g$ is also continuous.

Finally, $g(p) \neq 0$. By continuity of $g$, there is an open neighbourhood $V \subset U$ of $p$ such that $g(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in V$. This means that, for all $x \in V$, the matrix $(dF)_x$ has at least one $m \times m$ submatrix with non-vanishing determinant. So the original $F$ is a submersion on $V$.